# Linux Mint GUI stays black after login

Tags: linux-mint, boot, login

Suddenly this happens:
When I boot my noteback linux mint boots to the login screen. Then after I logged in the mouse cursor is visible centered on a black background. And thats where nothing more happens.
I tried to use `startx` but same problem there...stays black.

One thing. I removed `wpasupplicant` package before this happened. I'm sure I saw some "cinnamon" removing while the removal processed. Might it be that my cinnamon - which is the GUI isn't it? - has been removed aswell?

I'd like to give you more debug log / informations - but I'm not familiar in doing so. I'm used to work in Terminal for coding but something need to get into GUI for browsing.

EDIT: When trying to switch cinnamon on the login screen (the lambda symbol) this error message appears

```
Xsession: unable to launch "gnome-session-cinnamon" Xsession…."gnome-session-cinnamon" not found: falling back to default session.
```

Might it be that there really is an issue with cinnamon after the removal of `wpasupplicant` package?

EDIT2: I found a link describing that error message above: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=156684
They tell to `sudo apt-get install --reinstall cinnamon`. Funny thing is that I cannot connect to WIFI without GUI. Terminal needs `wpasupplicant` package which I recently removed ;) yeah!

Comment: Have you tried moving the `deb` package for cinnamon or wpasupplicant directly to the computer?

Comment: I just installed cinnamon again and then it worked

Comment: I tried installing cinnamon again, and then tried starting cinnamon, but received error `Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory. Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused. Window manager error: unable to open X display`.

Comment: I ran `sudo apt-get install --reinstall cinnamon`, then tried `> cinnamon` and received the same error as above. If I try `> xrefresh` I receive `cannot find display`. I have no external displays, just using a Lenovo E440 laptop.

Comment: @xetra11, after you installed cinnamon again, did the GUI automatically start again?

Comment: @Steve I cannot remember tbh. But I'm sure I tried this one and think it was the solution

Comment: boot a live-session and control in /var/log/apt/history from your installation what packages you have removed exactly  and if some upgrades are comming in.  Download from here http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=wpasupplicant the package you need. According which Mint and arch. Save the deb in the /home from your brocken System. Boot this switch to virtual console and install it with dpkg. After ypu have net-connection `sudo apt-get -f install` And reinstall all packages which were removed. good Luck. Backup were nice :D. s.c.n.r.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `cinnamon` depends on `network-manager` which in turn depends on `wpasupplicant`, that's why removing the latter also removed the former. To avoid wiping important stuff from your system the suggested course of action is

```
apt-mark auto wpasupplicant # mark the package as "auto", i.e. not needed by the user
apt-get autoremove          # remove unneeded packages
```

That way, `wpasupplicant` wouldn't be removed, since it's needed by other packages, even if you told the system you didn't need it.

Comment: I completed those commands. When I try to start cinnamon again, I receive `Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory. Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused. Window manager error: unable to open X display.`

Comment: @Steve my answer was intended to explain how to avoid the problem in the first place, since the OP seem to have resolved their issue somehow. You seem to have a slightly different problem. Do you have any GUI at all?

Comment: No, no GUI Dmitry.

Comment: @Steve Then the X server might have gone during upgrade (have you run `apt-get dist-upgrade`?) It's hard to tell what's wrong with your system without having access to it, but you could start by installing a display manager (`lightdm`? check if you have its config files in `/etc`) or even `xinit` to get X server back.